# Converting a four digit month year string to date in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have some data as follows:

```
data
1203
0323
0101
1005
1130
0226
```

So in every case, the first two digits are the month and the last two digits are the year. Is there anyway to easily map these to date for without making it an outright lookup table?

Here's what I am seeking

```
data date
1203 12/01/2003
0323 03/01/2023
0101 01/01/2001
1005 10/01/2005
1130 11/01/2030
0226 02/01/2026
```

In every case, I would like the day to be the first of that month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try building a valid date string with a year, month, and day component and then converting to a bona fide date using the `TO_DATE` function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '1203' AS dt
)

SELECT dt, TO_DATE(CONCAT('01', dt), 'DDMMYY') AS dt_out
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

Much the same as Tim's answer:

You want to cast from number to text (and if you data is text skip that, BUT if it's variant (from JSON or XML) you still need to cast to TEXT), then parse with [TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) as MM month, YY year in 2 column ([format tokens](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#supported-date-and-time-parts)). And you will get the 1st of each of those months

```
SELECT 
    column1, 
    to_date(column1::text, 'MMYY')
FROM VALUES
    (1203),
    (0323),
    (0101),
    (1005),
    (1130),
    (0226);
```

giving:

| COLUMN1 | TO_DATE(COLUMN1::TEXT, 'MMYY') |
| --- | --- |
| 1203 | 2003-12-01 |
| 323 | 2023-03-01 |
| 101 | 2001-10-01 |
| 1005 | 2005-10-01 |
| 1130 | 2030-11-01 |
| 226 | 2026-02-01 |